# New module always inactive in Module manager

Tags: magento2, module, third-party-module

I'm trying to install new module in `Magento 2.2.5` , i already enabled the module , when i checked the module status using `php bin/magento module:status` it is **active** , but the problem is the admin menu or configuration for this module does not exist. I tried to install it in new fresh  Magento repo and it shows up fine. Finally i checked at the Module Manage in `System > Tools > Web Setup Wizard`, when i opened the module manager it was shown inactive, i tried to install another new module and got this same problem happened when i install another new module too

Answer (score 0):

did you try to run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

after activating the module?

Comment: yes done that and any other every command